# How to add external image in magento2 pdp

Tags: javascript, magento2, gallery, fotorama, pdp

How can we add an external image for magento2 product detail page(not from the magento2 backend). I tried some stuff in the galley.phtml but not succeed. Is there anybody who can fix this, help me  please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to gallery.phtml

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $(document).on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            var $fotorama = jQuery('div.gallery-placeholder > div.fotorama');
            var fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama');
            $fotorama.on('fotorama:load', function fotorama_onLoad(e, fotorama, extra) {
                if (extra.frame.type === 'iframe') {
                    extra.frame.$stageFrame.html('<iframe align="middle" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="' + extra.frame.src + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>');
                }
            });
            fotorama.push({
                thumb: '<set your thumbnail image path>',
                'src': '<set your image/video url>',
                type: 'iframe',
                caption: '<set your caption>'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this fix my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions:

https://jsshowcase.com/question/how-to-add-external-image-in-magento2-pdp

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/309826/101754